# Spring mvc не находит бин @Service UserService

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

На данный момент изучаю Spring Security, и столкнулся с таким исключением -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUserService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.services.UserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.services.UserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Пробовал извращаться с Qualifier и ComponentScan , но не помогло. Может кто подскажет.

WebConfig -

```
public class WebConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebSecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

SpringConfig -

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan("com")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
    

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        // Do nothing instead of configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

JpaConfig -

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.repositories"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfog {

    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("*****");
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig -

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

UserRepository -

```
    @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    
        User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

UserService -

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User '%s' not found", username));
        }
        return user;
    }

}
```

UserEntity -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_user")
    private Long idUser;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public User() {
    }

    public Long getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" + "idUser=" + idUser + ", username=" + username + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password + ", active=" + active + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isActive();
    }
}
```

Role -

```
public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    ROLE_USER,
    ROLE_ADMIN;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name();
    }

}
```

Comment: Для инжекта нужно указывать название интерфейса, а не класса, которые его реализует. Инжектите `UserDetailsService` вместо `UserService`

Comment: @FirstSin `@Autowired private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;` тоже выдает такую ошибку

Comment: @SnejOK вы используете springboot? или же просто спринг, все может зависеть от того в каком пакете находятся ваши класы-компоненты

Comment: @denisKrivorutchko Использую спринг через java конфигурацию. Проблема в том, что все Сервиси у меня находятся в одном пакете, и все хорошо работали кроме UserService. Сейчас заметил что при инжекте в классе WebSecurityConfig любой бин не будет найден.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение добавив свой UserService в getRootConfigClasses().

Пример -

```
public class WebConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebSecurityConfig.class, UserService.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

Также если вы использует java JpaConfig, тогда следует добавить и его, дабы ваш репозиторий тоже инжектило.

Пример -

```
public class WebConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebSecurityConfig.class, JpaConfog.class, UserService.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

Comment: я в ету сторону и не посмотрел, потому как уже давно использую ботинок, а он делает ето на автомате, вобщем серавно лутше делать инжект через конструктор, тех компонентов в которых вы хотите бить уверены на 100%, иначе нужно будет организовать роботу контейнара  так что бы, он имел в контейнере зависимость которую он будет сетить.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае нужно делать инжекшн через конструктор в класе WebSecurityConfig и UserService потому как UserService является  обезательной зависимостью. Ето будет заставлят контейнер делать не нулевые инъекции

Comment: К сожалению ваш вариант тоже не помог. Но я все же наконец нашел решение. Я добавил в WebConfig, в getRootConfigClasses() свой класс UserService.

Comment: В любом случае благодарю за помощь